# Foreign Exchange rules INDIA

Tags: india, foreign-exchange, regulation

Hi I want to buy some hosting space for my website and for that I have to pay the hosting co. in dollars can anyone tell me what are the regulations and compliances I need to follow.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much to worry on buying domain names or other consumer goods like anti-virus license etc.

Just use your Indian credit card to pay.